# Syntax highlighting for semantex?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I don't know how to get syntax highlighting in TeXstudio (windows 10) with `semantex`. I found some guides on the internet but I'm not a programmer so not sure how to do it. Can someone help me?

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with the TeXstudio `.cwl` syntax to know how to do that. Also, one thing is getting the system to recognize command names; this is not a big deal, I guess, since there are essentially only a few object and class commands (`\NewObject`, `\NewVariableClass`, etc.) which are used to define them. On the other hand, getting it to recognize `key` names (especially the user-defined keys) might require black magic.

Comment: What is `semantex`?

Comment: @AlanXiang https://ctan.org/pkg/semantex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but an overview of the commands which a syntax highlighting system would need to be able to recognize:

There are five different commands for creating new classes, corresponding to different “class types”: `\NewVariableClass`, `\NewCohomologyClass`, `\NewSymbolClass`, `\NewDelimiterClass`, and `\NewSimpleClass`. Each of them has the syntax

```
\New<???>Class\<Class Name><extra syntax>
```

So for instance, `\NewVariableClass\MyVar` creates the class `\MyVar`. The `<extra syntax>` depends on the class type, but it’s usually options in `[...]`. A syntax highlighter should probably just ignore the `<extra syntax>` and interpret `\New<???>Class` as commands that create other commands.

There is one command, `\NewObject`, for creating new objects. It has the syntax

```
\NewObject\<Class>\<object><extra syntax>
```

So for instance, `\NewObject\MyVar\myobject` creates the object `\myobject` of class `\MyVar`. In other words, `\NewObject` should be regarded as a command that discards the first argument and defines a command whose name is the second argument. Again, it’s probably best to ignore the `<extra syntax>`, as this depends on the class type of the class `\<Class>`.

There is one predefined class, called `\SemantexBaseObject`.

Next, there are a couple of commands, `\SemantexSetup`, `\SetupClass`, and `\SetupObject`, which do what the name suggests. No magic there, they should just be recognized as any other commands.

There is a command, `\SemantexDelimiterSize`, which contains the size of the surrounding brackets.

There is a lot of keyval syntax in `semantex`, including a *lot* of user-defined keyval syntax. I think this part of the syntax is too complex to be recognized by a syntax highlighter. Therefore, recognizing the above commands is probably all you can do.

---

I finally managed to figure out the `.cwl` system, which turns out to be rather simple. Simply add a file `semantex.cwl` in [the appropriate folder](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-cwl-files-stored) with the following content:

```
\NewVariableClass{cmd}#d
\NewDelimiterClass{cmd}#d
\NewCohomologyClass{cmd}#d
\NewSymbolClass{cmd}#d
\NewSimpleClass{cmd}#d
\NewObject{Class}{cmd}#d
\SetupObject
\SetupClass
\SemantexSetup
\SemantexDelimiterSize
\SemantexBaseObject
```